# Scroll view is not working

Tags: android

Inside framelayout scrollview is not working.I have added scrollview inside frame layout .but scrolling is not working ..is there any other possible way?..please suggest me

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/maintable"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="1" >

                </TableLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: probably because the HorizontalScrollView is stealing the touch events. Have you tried removing the HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: i have tried ..not working

Comment: As first thing, change all the "fill_parent" to "match_parent" because fill_parent is deprecated. As second thing, the problem could be the height of the ScrollView. In this case is really usefull setting a different color to the background of every layout to see where they start and end, or using the new blueprint function in android layout designer from AS 2.3

Comment: changed .not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/maintable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="1" >

                </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need ScrollView + HorizontalScrollView?

Try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> <TableLayout android:id="@+id/maintable" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:stretchColumns="1" > </TableLayout> </HorizontalScrollView> </
    FrameLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i need scrollview

Comment: In that case, Try NestedScrollView instead of FrameLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

do want this? then use snaphelper class with adapter.